# How to select from a stored procedure in SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Is this possible at all?

```
...
Int32? Id = 1;
QDataContext qDataContext = new QDataContext();
var q= from p in qDataContext.GetProcedurePersonas(Id) 
       select p.name, p.last;
...
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult WcfService1.GetProcedurePersonasResult'.
>   'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' 
>   or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Also I have this and work perfectly

```
...
Int32? Id = 1;
QDataContext qDataContext = new QDataContext();
var q= qDataContext.GetProcedurePersonas(Id);
...
```

Comment: Why don't you try it whether it's possible or not?

Comment: If the return type is a collection then yes it should be possible.

Comment: From what you have posted I assume you have already implemented the SP, therefore as @MiklosBalogh has suggested why don't you just try it out yourself first?

Comment: i want result json serialize linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already have the

```
QDataContext qDataContext = new QDataContext();
var q= qDataContext.GetProcedurePersonas(Id);
```

and for instance you want to select something specific from q you may do.

```
var specific=(from c in q where c.columnvalue == yourValue select c.columnvalue).ToList();
```

to serialize to json you may use

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = jss.Serialize(specific);
```

Comment: also i need include "using System.Linq";
for some reason not appears in my system.

see you! ... muchas gracias..!!